# Graph library can't parse simple Array properties with an existing Document base collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

We have an existing CosmosDb collection that we use with the SQL API. We want to start using the Graph API against this collection. Using the `Microsoft.Azure.Graphs` NUGET version `0.3.1-preview` and performing the simple Gremlin query `g.V()` throws an Invalid Cast Exception:

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

After lots of trial and error, we narrowed it down to a property array of string values:

```
{
  "Roles": [ "user", "admin" ]
}
```

Converting this property to an object or removing this property fixes the issue, of course that is not a viable solution.

Is this a bug on the Graph SDK, on the Cosmos Db engine, on Gremlin, or simply not doable in Graph in general?

How do we solve this issue?